# Why this error " Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' " occur?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am a beginner of android.I have found this topic but, that was not helpful to me. I am getting this error.But I cannot figure out what is my problem??

Note : I am facing  " Could not find tools.jar " error  also.I am using external .jar file in lib folder.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
          compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
          buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
           useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'          

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0') {
            exclude module: 'httpcore'
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
           }
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'



}
```

Comment: Share you build.gradle file

Comment: build.gradle file is added

Answer (score 0):

I guess,you've downloaded and installed the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) instead of the Java Development Kit (JDK). The latter has the tools.jar, java.exe, javac.exe, etc.

Comment: I have downloaded JDK .....which system files are located at  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
```

with

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```